# Выбор последнего изображения из директории

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Бот получает документ ( изображение ) от пользователя и сохраняет их в директорию 'documents'

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["document"])
def get_photo(message):
    document_id = message.document.file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(document_id)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{config.token}/{file_info.file_path}', file_info.file_path)
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Успешно сохранено!')
```

Изображения сохраняются в следующем формате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо выбрать последний документ из директории, а далее уже работать с ним. (Например отправить пользователю обратно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from glob import glob

file_name = []

for jpg_file in glob('folder/*.JPG'):
    file_name.append(jpg_file)

print(file_name)
print(file_name[-1])

>>>
['folder\\file_22.JPG', 'folder\\file_23.JPG', 'folder\\file_24.JPG', 'folder\\file_25.JPG']
folder/file_25.JPG


...
file_name.append(jpg_file[7:])
...
>>>
['file_22.JPG', 'file_23.JPG', 'file_24.JPG', 'file_25.JPG']
file_25.JPG
```